# Validate checkbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want use to select at least a checkbox else it has to show error in the same page.I have done it using php but error is displaying in redirected file.I want to display the error in same page before redirecting .I don't want to display in other page.How to do this using jquery.I am callow in jquery. Can anybody assist help?

my code is,

```
<?php
include_once "../header/header.php";
$_SESSION['user_id'];
$_SESSION['project_name']; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Test</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <!-- The below url are required for dropdown -->
    <link href="http://localhost/Performance/Test/css/fselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://localhost/Performance/Test/js/fSelect.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(function() { 
            $('#filename').fSelect();
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>

</head>
<?php
    include_once "database.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(empty(isset($_POST['filename']))){
    echo "error";
  }
 }  
?>

<body style="background-color: white">
    <form method="post" action="RunTest.php" autocomplete="off">
    <input style="position:fixed; top:40px; right:25px; margin-right:4cm;" class="btn btn-success col-sm-1" type="submit" name="submit"  value="Save"/>
    <!--<input style="position:fixed; top:40px; right:10px;" class="btn btn-success col-sm-1" type="submit" onclick="ClearFields();" value="Clear"/>-->
            <div>       
                <select  name="filename[]" id="filename" multiple="multiple">
                    <optgroup label="Filename">
                        <?php
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_fsql)) {
                                echo "<option id='file' value='".$row['script']."'>".$row['script']."</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div><br/>
        </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

fselect.js

```
[![(function($) {

    $.fn.fSelect = function(options) {

        if ('string' === typeof options) {
            var settings = options;
        }
        else {
            var settings = $.extend({
                placeholder: 'Select some options',
                numDisplayed: 3,
                overflowText: '{n} selected',
                searchText: 'Search',
                showSearch: true,
                optionFormatter: false
            }, options);
        }


        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        function fSelect(select, settings) {
            this.$select = $(select);
            this.settings = settings;
            this.create();
        }


        /**
         * Prototype class
         */
        fSelect.prototype = {
            create: function() {
                this.settings.multiple = this.$select.is('\[multiple\]');
                var multiple = this.settings.multiple ? ' multiple' : '';
                this.$select.wrap('<div class="fs-wrap' + multiple + '" tabindex="0" />');
                this.$select.before('<div class="fs-label-wrap"><div class="fs-label">' + this.settings.placeholder + '</div><span class="fs-arrow"></span></div>');
                this.$select.before('<div class="fs-dropdown hidden"><div class="fs-options"></div></div>');
                this.$select.addClass('hidden');
                this.$wrap = this.$select.closest('.fs-wrap');
                this.$wrap.data('id', window.fSelect.num_items);
                window.fSelect.num_items++;
                this.reload();
            },

            reload: function() {
                if (this.settings.showSearch) {
                    var search = '<div class="fs-search"><input type="search" placeholder="' + this.settings.searchText + '" /></div>';
                    this.$wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').prepend(search);
                }
                this.idx = 0;
                this.optgroup = 0;
                this.selected = \[\].concat(this.$select.val()); // force an array
                var choices = this.buildOptions(this.$select);
                this.$wrap.find('.fs-options').html(choices);
                this.reloadDropdownLabel();
            },

            destroy: function() {
                this.$wrap.find('.fs-label-wrap').remove();
                this.$wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').remove();
                this.$select.unwrap().removeClass('hidden');
            },

            buildOptions: function($element) {
                var $this = this;

                var choices = '';
                $element.children().each(function(i, el) {
                    var $el = $(el);

                    if ('optgroup' == $el.prop('nodeName').toLowerCase()) {
                        choices += '<div class="fs-optgroup-label" data-group="' + $this.optgroup + '">' + $el.prop('label') + '</div>';
                        choices += $this.buildOptions($el);
                        $this.optgroup++;
                    }
                    else {
                        var val = $el.prop('value');

                        // exclude the first option in multi-select mode
                        if (0 < $this.idx || '' != val || ! $this.settings.multiple) {
                            var disabled = $el.is(':disabled') ? ' disabled' : '';
                            var selected = -1 < $.inArray(val, $this.selected) ? ' selected' : '';
                            var group = ' g' + $this.optgroup;
                            var row = '<div class="fs-option' + selected + disabled + group + '" data-value="' + val + '" data-index="' + $this.idx + '"><span class="fs-checkbox"><i></i></span><div class="fs-option-label">' + $el.html() + '</div></div>';

                            if ('function' === typeof $this.settings.optionFormatter) {
                                row = $this.settings.optionFormatter(row);
                            }

                            choices += row;
                            $this.idx++;
                        }
                    }
                });

                return choices;
            },

            reloadDropdownLabel: function() {
                var settings = this.settings;
                var labelText = \[\];

                this.$wrap.find('.fs-option.selected').each(function(i, el) {
                    labelText.push($(el).find('.fs-option-label').text());
                });

                if (labelText.length < 1) {
                    labelText = settings.placeholder;
                }
                else if (labelText.length > settings.numDisplayed) {
                    labelText = settings.overflowText.replace('{n}', labelText.length);
                }
                else {
                    labelText = labelText.join(', ');
                }

                this.$wrap.find('.fs-label').html(labelText);
                this.$wrap.toggleClass('fs-default', labelText === settings.placeholder);
                this.$select.change();
            }
        }


        /**
         * Loop through each matching element
         */
        return this.each(function() {
            var data = $(this).data('fSelect');

            if (!data) {
                data = new fSelect(this, settings);
                $(this).data('fSelect', data);
            }

            if ('string' === typeof settings) {
                data\[settings\]();
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Events
     */
    window.fSelect = {
        'num_items': 0,
        'active_id': null,
        'active_el': null,
        'last_choice': null,
        'idx': -1
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled)', function(e) {
        var $wrap = $(this).closest('.fs-wrap');
        var do_close = false;

        if ($wrap.hasClass('multiple')) {
            var selected = \[\];

            // shift + click support
            if (e.shiftKey && null != window.fSelect.last_choice) {
                var current_choice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
                var addOrRemove = ! $(this).hasClass('selected');
                var min = Math.min(window.fSelect.last_choice, current_choice);
                var max = Math.max(window.fSelect.last_choice, current_choice);

                for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                    $wrap.find('.fs-option\[data-index='+ i +'\]')
                        .not('.hidden, .disabled')
                        .each(function() {
                            $(this).toggleClass('selected', addOrRemove);
                        });
                }
            }
            else {
                window.fSelect.last_choice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            }

            $wrap.find('.fs-option.selected').each(function(i, el) {
                selected.push($(el).attr('data-value'));
            });
        }
        else {
            var selected = $(this).attr('data-value');
            $wrap.find('.fs-option').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            do_close = true;
        }

        $wrap.find('select').val(selected);
        $wrap.find('select').fSelect('reloadDropdownLabel');

        // fire an event
        $(document).trigger('fs:changed', $wrap);

        if (do_close) {
            closeDropdown($wrap);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', '.fs-search input', function(e) {
        if (40 == e.which) { // down
            $(this).blur();
            return;
        }

        var $wrap = $(this).closest('.fs-wrap');
        var matchOperators = /\[|\\{}()\[\]^$+*?.\]/g;
        var keywords = $(this).val().replace(matchOperators, '\\$&');

        $wrap.find('.fs-option, .fs-optgroup-label').removeClass('hidden');

        if ('' != keywords) {
            $wrap.find('.fs-option').each(function() {
                var regex = new RegExp(keywords, 'gi');
                if (null === $(this).find('.fs-option-label').text().match(regex)) {
                    $(this).addClass('hidden');
                }
            });

            $wrap.find('.fs-optgroup-label').each(function() {
                var group = $(this).attr('data-group');
                var num_visible = $(this).closest('.fs-options').find('.fs-option.g' + group + ':not(.hidden)').length;
                if (num_visible < 1) {
                    $(this).addClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        setIndexes($wrap);
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        var $el = $(e.target);
        var $wrap = $el.closest('.fs-wrap');

        if (0 < $wrap.length) {

            // user clicked another fSelect box
            if ($wrap.data('id') !== window.fSelect.active_id) {
                closeDropdown();
            }

            // fSelect box was toggled
            if ($el.hasClass('fs-label') || $el.hasClass('fs-arrow')) {
                var is_hidden = $wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').hasClass('hidden');

                if (is_hidden) {
                    openDropdown($wrap);
                }
                else {
                    closeDropdown($wrap);
                }
            }
        }
        // clicked outside, close all fSelect boxes
        else {
            closeDropdown();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        var $wrap = window.fSelect.active_el;
        var $target = $(e.target);

        // toggle the dropdown on space
        if ($target.hasClass('fs-wrap')) {
            if (32 == e.which) {
                $target.find('.fs-label').trigger('click');
                return;
            }
        }
        // preserve spaces during search
        else if (0 < $target.closest('.fs-search').length) {
            if (32 == e.which) {
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (null === $wrap) {
            return;
        }

        if (38 == e.which) { // up
            e.preventDefault();

            $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').removeClass('hl');

            var $current = $wrap.find('.fs-option\[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + '\]');
            var $prev = $current.prevAll('.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled)');

            if ($prev.length > 0) {
                window.fSelect.idx = parseInt($prev.attr('data-index'));
                $wrap.find('.fs-option\[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + '\]').addClass('hl');
                setScroll($wrap);
            }
            else {
                window.fSelect.idx = -1;
                $wrap.find('.fs-search input').focus();
            }
        }
        else if (40 == e.which) { // down
            e.preventDefault();

            var $current = $wrap.find('.fs-option\[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + '\]');
            if ($current.length < 1) {
                var $next = $wrap.find('.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled):first');
            }
            else {
                var $next = $current.nextAll('.fs-option:not(.hidden, .disabled)');
            }

            if ($next.length > 0) {
                window.fSelect.idx = parseInt($next.attr('data-index'));
                $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').removeClass('hl');
                $wrap.find('.fs-option\[data-index=' + window.fSelect.idx + '\]').addClass('hl');
                setScroll($wrap);
            }
        }
        else if (32 == e.which || 13 == e.which) { // space, enter
            e.preventDefault();

            $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').click();
        }
        else if (27 == e.which) { // esc
            closeDropdown($wrap);
        }
    });

    function setIndexes($wrap) {
        $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl').removeClass('hl');
        $wrap.find('.fs-search input').focus();
        window.fSelect.idx = -1;
    }

    function setScroll($wrap) {
        var $container = $wrap.find('.fs-options');
        var $selected = $wrap.find('.fs-option.hl');

        var itemMin = $selected.offset().top + $container.scrollTop();
        var itemMax = itemMin + $selected.outerHeight();
        var containerMin = $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop();
        var containerMax = containerMin + $container.outerHeight();

        if (itemMax > containerMax) { // scroll down
            var to = $container.scrollTop() + itemMax - containerMax;
            $container.scrollTop(to);
        }
        else if (itemMin < containerMin) { // scroll up
            var to = $container.scrollTop() - containerMin - itemMin;
            $container.scrollTop(to);
        }
    }

    function openDropdown($wrap) {
        window.fSelect.active_el = $wrap;
        window.fSelect.active_id = $wrap.data('id');
        window.fSelect.initial_values = $wrap.find('select').val();
        $wrap.find('.fs-dropdown').removeClass('hidden');
        $wrap.addClass('fs-open');
        setIndexes($wrap);
    }

    function closeDropdown($wrap) {
        if ('undefined' == typeof $wrap && null != window.fSelect.active_el) {
            $wrap = window.fSelect.active_el;
        }
        if ('undefined' !== typeof $wrap) {
            // only trigger if the values have changed
            var initial_values = window.fSelect.initial_values;
            var current_values = $wrap.find('select').val();
            if (JSON.stringify(initial_values) != JSON.stringify(current_values)) {
                $(document).trigger('fs:closed', $wrap);
            }
        }

        $('.fs-wrap').removeClass('fs-open');
        $('.fs-dropdown').addClass('hidden');
        window.fSelect.active_el = null;
        window.fSelect.active_id = null;
        window.fSelect.last_choice = null;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any checkboxes in your HTML? Also note that `radio` buttons with a pre-selected option make much more sense for occasions like this

Comment: You could use jquery to achieve this. Send your radio button as a POST and check if it contains anything, if not, then echo error, then in your success, check if html includes 'error' or whatever you chose to echo.

Comment: Are there any updates on this? How is everything proceeding? Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried like this it is working fine.

```
<script>
    //error showing if user does not select any uploaded jmx file.
  function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["filename"].value;  
        if (x == ''){
          jQuery('#filechoose_error').show();
          return false;             
       }
  }
</script>
```

In form,

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="RunTest.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" autocomplete="off">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <span><b>Filename</b></span>
                </div>
                <select  name="filename[]" id="filename" multiple="multiple">
                    <optgroup label="Filename">
                        <?php
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_fsql)) {
                            echo "<option id='file' value='".$row['script']."'>".$row['script']."</option>";
                                }
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            <!--display error-->
        <div style="display:none; text-align:center; color:red" class="error" id="filechoose_error" >&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;  * select a file</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to achieve what you want. Firstly, I have to say that I personally use jQuery AJAX, and generally jQuery notation for my JavaScript. It simply makes a lot of the code simple and easy to read. If you wish to do the same, you'll have to install a jQuery library and include it in your file as you would with any normal JavaScript or CSS file.

The AJAX function:

```
function sendData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "some_page.php",
        data : { checkBox : $("#idOfCheckbox:checked").val() },
        success: function (html) {
            //Success handling
            if( html.includes('notCheckedError') ) {
                //Show error message in an element by id
                $("#errorContainer").html("Error! You have not checked the checkbox.")
            }
            else {
               //Perform redirect
               window.location.href="/other_page.php";
           }
        }
    })
}
```

I chose to encapsulate the AJAX function into another function that can be called onclick, or however you choose to call it. You can also put the AJAX function into a document.ready function, and add a click event to it. I just chose this method because it makes for easy understanding.

*About the Ajax function*, we define the type of the data. Most common uses are `POST` and `GET`. In our case, I chose to go with `POST`. You can find out more about these data types [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).
Then we specify the URL, which is where we send our data variable.
Then we specify the data. Firstly we define our variable, *checkBox*, in this case. We then set the variable to be the value of the selected checkbox. We fetch this value by targeting the id of the checkbox. You have many options as to how you can select different elements, id, class, name etc.

Then we get to our success handling, where we check if the html includes (this is the html from our *some_page.php*) a specific string that we defined. This string is what we will `echo` as an error in our PHP file. If the PHP file does not contain the string, then it will proceed with the redirect, else it will paste our defined error message from the AJAX function into the error container.

Now, after we called our function, our *some_page.php* will either have received the post variable *checkBox*, or not. so in our PHP file, we'll need to perform a check to see if the POST actually contains a value or not. If the value is empty, then we throw the error that we are checking for in our AJAX function. I.e. the *notCheckedError*.

The PHP file will look something like this:

```
<?php
if(!$_POST['checkBox']) {
    echo 'notCheckedError';
}
else {
    //Everything is ok, the AJAX will perform the redirect.
}
?>
```

Now, I don't know how your HTML looks like in regards to your checkbox, but it could look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="idOfCheckbox" name="nameOfCheckbox" value="1">
```

You could then have a button to call the AJAX function,

```
<button onclick="sendData();">Send data!</button>
```

The error container (can be a div or span element, etc.):

```
<div id="errorContainer"></div>
```

*Worth noting*, you could set your checkbox property to be checked by default by using the `checked` property:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="idOfCheckbox" name="nameOfCheckbox" value="1" checked>
```

or by the use of jQuery:

```
$("#idOfCheckbox").attr('checked', true);
```

or,

```
$("#idOfCheckbox").prop('checked');
```

That way, your user won't have to actively click it for it to be checked.

Another option is to check for the boolean value of the checkbox, to see whether it has been checked or not. Then you can choose to call the AJAX function based on the evaluation being true.

To get the boolean value of a checkbox:

```
$("#idOfCheckbox").is(':checked');
```

you can then do,

```
if( $("#idOfCheckbox").is(':checked') ) {
    //logic for check goes here
}
else {
    //Error
}
```

Hope this helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkboxId').is(':checked')
```

This will return true or false depends on the checkbox status